# Word 2013 is slow when opening files from network share

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, microsoft-office-2013

I have users running on a Citrix farm, 4 terminal servers in load balance running Windows 2K8R2 and Office 2013.

Some users have problems with very slow opening of files over the network share they use both home folders and shared folders from a Win2K12R2 server. The problem seem to be with Word only, opening a 500kb file can take 30 seconds while opening a 110mb .xls file from the same share can be almost instant. The problem is also only while opening files. Open Word alone is quickly done, but loading a file takes ages.

Ive ruled out the AV. We use Sophos Endpoint Security, disabling it on both TS and file server showed no difference in performance. Compression has never been enabled on the drive the share is stored on and caching has been disabled. Windows Search has never been installed on the file server, but it is on the terminal servers (dunno if it indexes network drives?). Windows Search service has been disabled on all TS's as well. None of these things has helped so far.

Anyone had the same problem and know a solution?

Comment: Does it matter whether the file is opened through Word's File->Open vs. opening from the network share with Windows Explorer?

Comment: Nope. As soon as the try to open a file located on a network share it slows down, how they do it doesnt matter.

Comment: I've done some more testing with one of the users. A temp fix is to run Word with the /safe parameter, safemode seems to fix the problem. Can't say for sure what it disables that makes the problem go away. I've tested all the add-ins and none of them seem to be the culprit.

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found; delete normal.dotm file fixed it.